# Laravel / AsgardCMS validation of complex/composite entities

Tags: laravel, validation, request, composite, asgardcms

I got an Address entity which is in a (polymorphic) relation with UserProfileA and UserProfileB.

This is an implementation choice and i don't want the user be aware of this, so in my backend there is a single form for a UserProfileX data and UserProfileX->Address data.

Since i'm using vue in the backend this also means that i have an API endpoint which will receive a multidimensional array containig all the profile data plus an 'address' field with an array with all the Address fields.

I know i could structure my Request as follow to validate all the data, but i would like to know if there is a way to re-use Address validation rules in different requests for it to be less error-prone, possibly reusing directly CreateAddressRequest.

I also know i can make a custom validation rule but i don't know how to call already existings validation rules.

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'profile_field_a' => [ ... ],
        'profile_field_b' => [ ... ],

        'address'         => [ ... ],
        'address.field_c' => [ ... ],
        'address.field_d' => [ ... ],
    ];
}
```